# Product regular price calculation based on 2 custom fields in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In Woocommerce I have set 2 custom fields in the admin in the pricing section under Woocommerce default prices fields: Margin rate and Purchase price.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how can I auto update the product price (regular price field) based on the calculation below:

```
 $product_price = $rate_margin * $purchase_price;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> You should add alway add the code that is used for your additional pricing fields in your question.

The code below **works only for simple product type** and is:

1. displaying and saving 2 custom fields: "Margin rate" and "Purchase price".
2. saving a new product price calculated from that 2 custom fields values.

> Before, you will need to remove your code that is generating that 2 custom fields *(as it will be replaced by mine)*.

```php
// Adding and displaying additional product pricing custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'additional_product_pricing_option_fields', 50 );
function additional_product_pricing_option_fields() {
    $domain = "woocommerce";
    global $post;

    echo '</div><div class="options_group pricing show_if_simple">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_rate_margin',
        'label'         => __("Rate margin", $domain ),
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'description'   => __("Rate margin explanation goes here…", $domain ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ) );


    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_purchase_price',
        'label'         => __("Purchase price", $domain ) . ' ('. get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'description'   => __("Purchase price explanation goes here…", $domain ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ) );

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="_custom_price_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';
}

// Utility function that save "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
function saving_rate_margin_and_purchase_price( $product ) {
    // Security check
    if ( isset($_POST['_custom_price_nonce']) && ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_custom_price_nonce']) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Save "Rate margin" custom field value
    if( isset($_POST['_rate_margin']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data('_rate_margin', sanitize_text_field( (float) $_POST['_rate_margin'] ) );
    }
    // Save "Purchase_price" custom field value
    if( isset($_POST['_rate_margin']) && isset($_POST['_purchase_price']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data('_purchase_price', sanitize_text_field( (float) $_POST['_purchase_price'] ) );
    }
}

// Utility function: Calculate and save product price from the "Rate margin" and the "Purchase price" custom fields
function calculate_and_save_new_product_price( $product ) {
    // Disable when product is on sale
    if( isset($_POST['_sale_price']) && $_POST['_sale_price'] > 0 ){
        return;
    }

    // Calculate and save the new price
    if( isset($_POST['_rate_margin']) && isset($_POST['_purchase_price'])
    && $_POST['_rate_margin'] > 0 && $_POST['_purchase_price'] > 0 ) {

        // Catch the pricing data
        $rate_margin    = (float) $_POST['_rate_margin'];
        $purchase_price = (float) $_POST['_purchase_price'];
        $active_price   = (float) $product->get_price();

        // Calculating new price
        $new_price = $rate_margin * $purchase_price;

        // If the active price is different from the calculated new price
        if( $new_price !== $active_price ) {
            // Update regular price and active price with new calculated price
            $product->set_price( $new_price );
            $product->set_regular_price( $new_price );
        }
    }
}

// Saving and calculating prices
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'update_product_meta_data', 100, 1 );
function update_product_meta_data( $product ) {

    // Saving "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
    saving_rate_margin_and_purchase_price( $product ); // <== To be removed if not used with the first function

    // Calculate and save product price from the "Rate margin" and the "Purchase price" custom fields
    calculate_and_save_new_product_price( $product );
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).* Tested and works.

Comment: Works perfectly with simple products. How can I use it also for variable products? Thanks.