# Why does my code does not change the amount of the subscription in woocommerce in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

The following code is based on [Product regular price calculation based on 2 custom fields in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718312/product-regular-price-calculation-based-on-2-custom-fields-in-woocommerce-3/52728750#52728750) answer code:

```
// Adding and displaying additional product pricing custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'additional_product_pricing_option_fields', 50 );
function additional_product_pricing_option_fields() {
    $domain = "woocommerce";
    global $post;

    echo '</div><div class="options_group pricing show_if_simple show_if_external show_if_composite">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_purchase_price',
        'label'         => __("Prix d'achat ($) (si supérieur à 0, il calcule le prix régulier de vente)", $domain ) . ' ('. get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'description'   => __("Prix d'achat ($) (si supérieur à 0, il calcule le prix régulier de vente)", $domain ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ) );

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="_custom_price_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';

}

// Utility function that save "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
function saving_rate_margin_and_purchase_price( $product ) {
    // Security check
    if ( isset($_POST['_custom_price_nonce']) && ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_custom_price_nonce']) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Save "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
    if(isset($_POST['_purchase_price']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data('_purchase_price', sanitize_text_field( (float) $_POST['_purchase_price'] ) );
    }
}

// Utility function: Calculate and save product price from the "Rate margin" and the "Purchase price" custom fields
function calculate_and_save_new_product_price( $product ) {
    // Disable when product is on sale
    if( isset($_POST['_sale_price']) && $_POST['_sale_price'] > 0 ){
        return;
    }

    // Calculate and save the new price
    if(isset($_POST['_purchase_price'])
    && $_POST['_purchase_price'] > 0 ) {

        // Catch the pricing data
        $rate_margin    = (float) get_option( 'dbi_example_plugin_options' )['pctrate'];
        $purchase_price = (float) $_POST['_purchase_price'];
        $active_price   = (float) $product->get_price();

        // Calculating new price
        $new_price = (100-$rate_margin)/100 * $purchase_price;

        // If the active price is different from the calculated new price
        if( $new_price !== $active_price ) {
            // Update regular price and active price with new calculated price
            $product->set_price( $new_price );
            update_post_meta($product->get_id(),'_subscription_price',$new_price);
            $product->set_regular_price( $new_price );
        }
    }
}

// Saving and calculating prices
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'update_product_meta_data' );

function update_product_meta_data( $product ) {

    // Saving "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
    saving_rate_margin_and_purchase_price( $product ); // <== To be removed if not used with the first function

    // Calculate and save product price from the "Rate margin" and the "Purchase price" custom fields
    calculate_and_save_new_product_price( $product );
}
```

I want that code can edit the amount of a subscription in woocommerce in wordpress in php but it works only with a simple product, it does not affect the recurring price of a subscription, why ?

It's the code of a plugin I'm developping but it does not work as expected as it does not affect  the price of a subscription even if there is a update post meta function

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
// Adding and displaying additional product pricing custom fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'additional_product_pricing_option_fields', 50);
function additional_product_pricing_option_fields()
{
    $domain = "woocommerce";
    global $post;

    echo '</div><div class="options_group pricing show_if_simple show_if_external show_if_composite">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id'            => '_purchase_price',
        'label'         => __("Prix d'achat ($) (si supérieur à 0, il calcule le prix régulier de vente)", $domain) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_purchase_price', true),
        'description'   => __("Prix d'achat ($) (si supérieur à 0, il calcule le prix régulier de vente)", $domain),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
    ));

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="_custom_price_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';
}


// Saving and calculating prices
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_product_meta_data', 12 );

function update_product_meta_data($post_id)
{

    if ( empty( $_POST['_wcsnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wcsnonce'], 'wcs_subscription_meta' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    // Saving "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
    saving_rate_margin_and_purchase_price($product); // <== To be removed if not used with the first function

    // Calculate and save product price from the "Rate margin" and the "Purchase price" custom fields
    calculate_and_save_new_product_price($product);
}

// Utility function that save "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
function saving_rate_margin_and_purchase_price($product)
{
    // Security check
    if (isset($_POST['_custom_price_nonce']) && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_custom_price_nonce'])) {
        return;
    }

    // Save "Rate margin" and "Purchase_price" custom fields values
    if (isset($_POST['_purchase_price'])) {
        $product->update_meta_data('_purchase_price', (float) $_POST['_purchase_price']);
    }
}

// Utility function: Calculate and save product price from the "Rate margin" and the "Purchase price" custom fields
function calculate_and_save_new_product_price($product)
{
    // Disable when product is on sale
    if (isset($_POST['_sale_price']) && $_POST['_sale_price'] > 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Calculate and save the new price
    if (
        isset($_POST['_purchase_price'])
        && $_POST['_purchase_price'] > 0
    ) {

         // Catch the pricing data
         $rate_margin    = (float) isset(get_option( 'dbi_example_plugin_options' )['pctrate'])?get_option( 'dbi_example_plugin_options' )['pctrate']:10;
         $purchase_price = (float) $_POST['_purchase_price'];
         $active_price   = (float) $product->get_price();
 
         // Calculating new price
         $new_price = (100-$rate_margin)/100 * $purchase_price;
 
         // If the active price is different from the calculated new price
         if( $new_price !== $active_price ) {
             // Update regular price and active price with new calculated price
            $product->set_regular_price( $new_price );
            $product->set_price( $new_price );
            $product->update_meta_data('_subscription_price', wc_format_decimal($new_price));
            $product->save();
         }
    }
}
```